# What role-playing games don't feature experience?

Tags: game-recommendation

I've never played a tabletop role-playing game, but when I was young I played a lot of role-playing video games, and I never liked the experience system they all used.

I won't say that everything from that concept is bad, and to be honest I'm not interested in the pro and cons of xp.

I just would like to know if some role-playing games (tabletop games, I started to speak about video games, but it's not my interest here) without xp exist, commercial or home-made, and if so, what are they? How can I find the rules for them - are there some websites available with their rules?

Comment: Good question. There are at least a few, like [Fate](http://www.faterpg.com/) by Evil Hat which is [free to download and use](http://www.evilhat.com/home/fate-core-downloads/) (really), but others may be able to put together a more complete answer.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. There are dozens, maybe hundreds, of XP-less RPGs, and even more which use XP in ways you might not object to. Open-ended lists don't usually make good answers, so can you narrow things down for us a bit? What don't you like about XP, and are you interested only in free games? And since you have 20+ rep on another site, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: Do you mean no XP system (but still some system of character advancement)  or no system of character advancement at all? (Ie static character abilities, skills, etc)

Comment: I play with a DM that doesn't award experience, but tells us when we can level up (to keep things interesting/begin planning more difficult challenges). It's worth noting that we were using Pathfinder so there were no XP costs for things like item creation or developing spells. I believe DnD 4e has no XP costs as well, as I played a similar style with another group. Basically what I'm saying is that it can work to ignore XP gain.

Comment: We *really* need to know what you dislike about XP in order to give useful answers. Character advancement of any sort? Waiting for a bar to fill up before advancing? Getting XP mostly from combat and not from role-playing? Who decides how much XP you get? What kind of advancement XP grants the character? There are games with all, some, or none of these features --and dozens of others-- in any combination you can imagine, and not all of them use "experience points" to mean what you're probably familiar with.

Comment: I'm voting to put this question on hold. The range of possible answers is really, really broad. I could list hundreds of games and never get close to a definitive answer to your question. How will you choose between answers with only one possible solution to your question? What should one write to provide a good answer to you? Once you edit this question to make it less broad (see BESW's comment for ideas on how) we're going to vote for reopening. Remember: putting your question on hold is a way to prevent precocious answering to a still unfocused question, not a punishment. And welcome to SE!

Comment: Hey Bob.  See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands.  There are thousands of extant RPGs and I would venture to say at least a third of them don't have XP per se. Some do advancement in other ways, some don't have advancement. We frown on list questions here, and you see the start of a hundred-long list below. If you can be more specific about what you want and why, what problem you're trying to solve? A game like X without XP, or different kinds of XP-less advancement mechanic?

Comment: The answer is "Yes, such games exist." Beyond that though, we can't give you a list because there are zomg so many. Check out the [RPGGeek database](http://www.rpggeek.com) for a taste of how many games exist. Lots don't have XP.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [GURPS](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/) as a xp less game.  In GURPS, you build a character using a point system.  Extra points can be awarded at the end of a session, but not because you passed the arbitrary xp threshold for the next level.  The GURPS website has a Lite version that will give you the basic gameplay mechanics.

Comment: But the question is asking for a system without XP, not a system without levels.

Comment: The extra points in GURPS are not experience points.  There is nothing you can do in the game that will get you any experience points.  The arbitrary points given by the game master, are merely to allow characters to grow.  You could have a game master that never gives out extra points.  It would be akin to a game master telling everyone to advance to the next level regardless of what they did.

Answer (score 2):

The **[Fate](http://www.faterpg.com/)** system and its various incarnations do not use experience points. Some variants like [Spirit of the Century](http://www.faterpg.com/dl/sotc-srd.html#the-long-game-advancement) and the new [Fate Core](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/advancement-change) do character advancement as part of milestones, while others like [Diaspora](http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/diaspora-srd.html#id86) or [Edgerunner](http://edgerunner.merttorun.com/characters/#the-ghost) don't have character "advancement" at all, just transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Doctor Who: Adventures in Time and Space by Cubicle 7 games has no experience points system.
The GM is of course free to say that the characters have learned from their experiences and can add skills or traits,  including negative traits, if they feel it is appropriate,  but there aren't any levels or XP.

Link:

http://www.cubicle7.co.uk/our-games/doctor-who-aitas/